# AXIOS: Can I send more than one Data item to an API in a POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, axios

So I have a form that collects data, and gets sent to an API using myForm = new FormData(). One of the items being populated in the model, however, has multiple attributes in the MongoDB model. Since the form has to have 1-to-1 key-pair relationships, I can't send it over as an object. So, as a solution, I build the object in my controller, and I'd like to send it over with other misc. form data (startLocation object in the code below).

Looking specifically at the code below, I was thinking I would be able to do it using **data: myForm, startLocation**, but, sadly, this does not work. Is there a good way to do this? Am I just screwing up the syntax?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { showAlert } from './alerts';

export const createTour = async myForm => {
  try {
    const startLocation = {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-80.185942, 25.774772],
      address: '47 Bowman Lane, Kings Park, NY 11754',
      description: 'New York'
    };

    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      /* headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${myForm._boundary}`
      }, */
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tours',
      data: myForm
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', 'NEW TOUR CREATED!');
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        location.assign('/');
      }, 1500);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Example from axios, `data`'s value should be a JSON object:

```
// Send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

In your case, try following:

```
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      /* headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${myForm._boundary}`
      }, */
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tours',
      data:{
         form: myForm,
         location: startLocation
      }
    });
```

Then you should be able to get both form data and location data at your backend.

Ref: [Axios API](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api)